# VTK OpenGL objects (3D texture) access from CUDA‏

Tags: opengl, cuda, vtk

Is there any proper way to access the low level OpenGL objects of VTK in order to modify them from a CUDA/OpenCL kernel using the openGL-CUDA/OpenCL interoperability feature?

Specifically, I would want to get the GLuint (or unsigned int) member from vtkOpenGLGPUVolumeRayCastMapper that points to the Opengl 3D Texture object where the dataset is stored, in order to bind it to a CUDA Surface to be able to access and modify its values from a CUDA kernel implemented by me.

For further information, the process that I need to follow is explained here:
http://rauwendaal.net/2011/12/02/writing-to-3d-opengl-textures-in-cuda-4-1-with-3d-surface-writes/
where the texID object used there (in Steps 1 and 2) is the equivalent to what I want to retrieve from VTK.

At a first look at the vtkOpenGLGPUVolumeRayCastMapper functions, I don't find an easy way to do this, rather than maybe creating a vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper subclass, but even in that case I am not sure what should I modify exactly, since I guess that some other members depend on the 3D Texture values, and should be also updated after modifying it.

So, do you know some way to do this?

Lots of thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing might work, but you could probably avoid it if you wanted. The important thing is that you get the order of the GL/CUDA API calls in the right order.

First, you have to register the texture with CUDA. This is done using:

```
cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&cuda_graphics_resource, texture_handle,
GL_TEXTURE_3D, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsSurfaceLoadStore);
```

with the stipulation that texture_handle is a GLuint written to by a call to glGenTextures(...)

Once you have registered the texture with CUDA, you can create the surface which can be read or written to in your kernel.

The only thing you have to worry about from here is that vtk does not use the texture in between a call to cudaGraphicsMapResources(...) and cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(...). Everything else should just be standard CUDA.

Also once you map the texture to CUDA and write to it within a kernel, there is no additional work besides unmapping the texture. GL will get the modified texture the next time it is used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that was not really the doubt. The main issue is regading VTK, not the Interop.

Comment: First, the access to the VTK GLuint is not implemented, since it is handled as a private member. Maybe I could subclass it and create a function to get access.
Even then, another issue arises. Since VTK is thought to handle static volumes, my guess is that VTK creates additional data, apart from the texture, when the VTK volume object is created. If I modify only the texture it from outside (CUDA), most of the additional data stored in the object would become obsolete. So, the big problem is how to handle the robustness of the object when it is being modified from outside without him noticing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VTK, but sure, you could subclass as long as it's protected and not private. If it is private as you say, you can query GL for the currently bound texture, but you would have to know when VTK is making calls to glBindTexture(). This assumes you are writing your own shaders, and wouldn't work if VTK handles all of that. As far as I know, there isn't any information stored by OpenGL that is invalidated by writing texel values in a CUDA kernel. It's computationally costly to resend (obsolete) texels to OpenGL more than once, so I doubt VTK does that, but I can't say.

Comment: Actually, the variable is protected, so I could gain access to it easily. The information that I mention as Invalidated is not from OpenGL, but from VTK, since probably some accelerating structures and additional calculations (for example, a gradient field associated to the volume) are calculated when a a new volume is assigned to it, and since VTK would not know of this CUDA modification, the additional data would become obsolete, since it was calculated when the initial volume was assigned to it using the normal VTK interface. I guess only an VTK expert could answer this :P. But thanks!